# Countifs doesn't work with specified worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Hello I have a some code that contains a CountIf formula. It worked fine when the range for the formula was the activesheet however now that I have attempted to specify a worksheet for the range suddenly its giving me an unable to get the countifs property of the worksheetfunction class error.

```
Sub MonthlyAdd()
Dim Category(7 To 10) As Variant
Dim Ar As Variant
Dim Br As Variant
Dim Catgry As String
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim Comp As Variant
Dim tot As Long
Dim item As Variant


For k = 2 To 13

With Worksheets("Log")

Ar = .Cells(k, 6).Value2

Br = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(.Cells(k, 6), 0)

For i = 7 To 10



Category(i) = .Cells(1, i).Value

Catgry = Category(i)

'This is the original line this line works fine

Cells(k, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)), "=" & Catgry & "*", Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)), ">=" & Ar, Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)), "<=" & Br)

'this is the same line except I have specified a worksheet within the range, suddenly it doesn't work

Cells(k, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("C3", .Range("C3").End(xlDown)), "=" & Catgry & "*", .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)), ">=" & Ar, 
.Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)), "<=" & Br)


Next i

Next k

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All range objects in that line have to be proceeded by `Worksheets("Log").` or use `with Worksheets("Log")` and a `.` before each range.

Comment: @Warcupine I've updated my code as suggested but now I'm getting an unable to get the countifs property of the worksheetfunction class error

Comment: Make sure all the ranges you're passing in to Countifs are all the same size...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is happening here and the other two similar statements:

```
 Worksheets("Log").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
'[^^ adequately qualified ^^] [^not adqtly qualified^]
```

Strictly speaking, to *fully* qualify, the workbook object should be included also.

While you're specifying the [Log] tab for the first A3, you're not specifying what tab the second A3 is on. Excel will default to the currently active tab, which is probably not [Log] - causing the error.

Replace your single line of code with the following, laid out for easy reading:

```
With Workbooks("EnterYourWorkbookName").Worksheets("Log")
    .Cells(k, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    .Range("C3", .Range("C3").End(xlDown)), "=" & Catgry & "*", _
    .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)), ">=" & Ar, _
    .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)), "<=" & Br)
End With
```

Comment: Unfortunately I now get the  unable to get the countifs property of the worksheetfunction class error.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `.Range("C3", .Range("C3").End(xlDown))` and `Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown))` have the same number of rows.

Comment: @TimWilliams - you're right, what a miss! Thanks for spotting. Corrected.

Comment: @BigBen - Also correct. @Drawleeh, you might want to consider Ben's point here. Unless you have something elsewhere that forces the rows to always have same count, it might be better to stick to only performing `xlDown` once and then use an `Offset` to translate across to other columns.